# Is there a good way to capture AJAX traffic during a JMeter test?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

We're looking to start doing some load testing and have experimented with JMeter before. The main complaint is that our current tests don't record any of the AJAX traffic in the web application. Is it possible to record traffic during the tests?

Comment: umm... There's no "Ajax traffic", since Ajax is not a communication protocol. Ajax uses XMLHttpRequest over HTTP, which is recorded / replayed by JMeter just like any other HTTP request. So it's not clear what do you mean by your question. Please try to come up with specific scenario, where JMeter did not record as you expected (See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

JMeter records Ajax Traffic in the application, all requests will be nested inside a [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller).

It is just that by default it will play them sequentially and not in parallel.

So:

- response time will be sum of Main + Ajax requests response time
- Load simulation will not be highly impacted as parallelism due to load testing will be simulated

Note there is a 3rd party plugin that provides parallel execution:

- https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md

You can install it using JMeter-Plugins plugin manager plugin.